# What is holding me back from using Aero on Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, aero

I decided to install win 7 64 bit I have a geforce 7950 GX2 and aero isn't working 
I've installed the 8.16.11.9107 x64 driver and still nothing Im not sure what I'm meant to do?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to re-run the Aero / Windows Experience Index assessment.

The easiest way to do this is to press <kbd>Windows Flag Key</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> to get in to system properties (or right click on computer, then properties).

Next, click on the "Windows Experience Index" text, then, in the bottom right hand corner, click on "Re-run the assessment"

I advise that you close everything you do not need open before running this as it will give you the highest score available for your hardware.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wil - Just FYI, if you use alt+print screen it will capture just the active window, so you won't have to crop the image.

Comment: I dont use print screen any more! Use the Vista / 7 snipping tool set to a shortcut... I just press ctrl+alt+s, and then drag a rectangle around the item and it does the magic! using the snipping tool, I then draw on it and save! does all the hard work for me!

Comment: That is pretty handy!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have hardware that supports aero, it may not work immediately after installing Windows 7 due to display adapter driver issues.  So, you'll start with a non-aero theme.  Updating the display drivers won't change that theme.

I've had this same issue.  Aero didn't work after install.  I downloaded the most appropriate drivers I could find (I installed Windows 7 x64, but all I could find were Vista x64 drivers for this Nvidia adapter, but they did work) and I still wasn't seeing aero effects.  That's because I was currently assigned a non-aero theme.  Of course, all I had to do was simply switch to an aero theme.

Sorry if this is too obvious of a suggestion, but it took me a while to figure it out.